# Determine the zero set of quadratic function in two variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following function
$$f(x_1, x_2)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
c_4 & c_5 & c_6\\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2 \\
x_1 x_2\\
x_2^2
\end{array}\right)
$$

with $c_1, \ldots, c_6$ given.

I want to know the zero set (or, in abuse of the concept, the "kernel") of $f$, i.e. the set $\{(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | f(x_1, x_2)= 0 \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$.

Additionally: Is there any general theory for such type problems?

Comment: The word kernel is usually used only for homomorphisms, which your map is not. Your set is usually called the zero set of the two polynomials. Algebraic Geometry studies such objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have the equations

$$c_1 x_1^2 + c_2 x_1 x_2 + c_3 x_2^2 = 0$$

$$c_4 x_1^2 + c_5 x_1 x_2 + c_6 x_2^2 = 0$$

Using the quadratic formula, we can factor each equation to look like $(p x_1 + q x_2)(r x_1 + s x_2)$.  So the first equation gives a pair of lines through the origin, as does the second, and we're intersecting these.  (Of course these lines might have complex slope, in which case you only see the origin if you're working over $\mathbb{R}$.  They also might be two copies of the same line, in which case it just looks like a single line.)  Anyway, the possible intersections are:

- Just the point (0,0);
- One line through the origin; or
- Two lines through the origin.

The first case happens for almost every choice of $c_1, \ldots, c_6$, while the last case happens only when the two equations are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: Indeed, that's it. It solves my particular problem. However, it would be nice to have a solution which also works for $n$ equations in $n$ variables. Thus, I posted a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1435110/124737).